# Use custom objects for RDL - SSRS (Reporting Services)

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, ssrs-2008-r2, rdl

I use VS 2008 for designer RDL files and Deploy in Report Server SSRS.
I use VS 2012 .NET 4.5 for my ASP.NET application for render report in PDF or Excel format, and send to Browser. Now, I want migrate RDLC (Local Reports) to RDL.

My question:

***Can I Use custom objects (several List of my entities) as the source for Remote Reports (RDL)?***, ***not RDLC*** ?

I use

```
private ReportExecutionService reportExecutionService = new ReportExecutionService();   // Web Service proxy

 reportExecutionService.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            reportExecutionService.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Properties.Settings.Default.ReportBrowserUser
                , Properties.Settings.Default.ReportBrowserPass
                , Properties.Settings.Default.ReportBrowserDomain);

            //reportExecutionService.Url = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Reporting.ReportExecutionService.Url");
            reportExecutionService.Url = Reporting.Properties.Settings.Default.ReportExecutionServiceUrl;

            reportExecutionService.PreAuthenticate = true;
            reportExecutionService.ExecutionHeaderValue = new ExecutionHeader();
```

List, my Entities as "Datasource" to populate my Report:

```
  public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            var empresa = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request["empresa"]);
            var mediador = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request["mediador"]);
            List<TablaEvolucionValorAnterior> listaPolizas = DatosGrafica.GetTablaEvolucionPolizasVentas(empresa, mediador);
            List<TablaEvolucionValorAnterior> listaPrimas = DatosGrafica.GetTablaEvolucionPrimasVentas(empresa, mediador);
            List<TablaRamosVentas> listaRamos = DatosGrafica.GetTablaRamosVentas(empresa, mediador);
```

**RDLC**

```
<DataSets>
    <DataSet Name="TablaRamosVentas">
      <Fields>
        <Field Name="Ramo">
          <DataField>Ramo</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>

         ...

  <rd:DataSetInfo>
        <rd:ObjectDataSourceSelectMethod>GetTablaRamosVentas</rd:ObjectDataSourceSelectMethod>
        <rd:ObjectDataSourceSelectMethodSignature>System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Graficas.Entidades.TablaRamosVentas] GetTablaRamosVentas(Int32, Int32)</rd:ObjectDataSourceSelectMethodSignature>
        <rd:ObjectDataSourceType>Graficas.Bll.DatosGrafica, Graficas, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null</rd:ObjectDataSourceType>
      </rd:DataSetInfo>

</DataSet>
```

Any suggestions about it?

**Updated**

I have seen Wrapper class for ReportExecution:

https://github.com/aistrate/B4F/blob/f70276a5ac7d220b581d14e6d8e2f62d79083eea/TotalGiro/Reports/ReportExecutionWrapper.cs

GetReportContent method manage one DataSet, like

```
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
            ds.WriteXml(sw, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
            sw.Close();
```

Full method

```
        public byte[] GetReportContent(DataSet ds, string[] extraParams)
        {
            if (extraParams.Length != extraParamNames.Count)
                throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(
                    "[ReportExecutionWrapper] Wrong number of extra parameters passed in to method Run() [expected {0}, was {1}].",
                    extraParamNames.Count, extraParams.Length));

            initialize();

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
            ds.WriteXml(sw, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
            sw.Close();

            parameters[0].Value = sb.ToString();

            for (int i = 0; i < extraParams.Length; i++)
                parameters[i + 1].Value = extraParams[i];

            reportExecutionService.SetExecutionParameters(parameters, "nl-NL");

            string extension, mimeType, encoding;
            Warning[] warnings;
            string[] streamIds;
            byte[] reportContent = reportExecutionService.Render("PDF", "",
                                        out extension, out mimeType, out encoding, out warnings, out streamIds);
            return reportContent;
        }
```

In RDL file, https://github.com/aistrate/B4F/blob/f70276a5ac7d220b581d14e6d8e2f62d79083eea/Reports/Reporting%20Project/Reporting%20Project/Reporting%20Project/FiscalYearISB.rdl

Define ReportParameter "DataSource" (type String)

```
  <ReportParameters>
    <ReportParameter Name="DataSource">
      <DataType>String</DataType>
      <DefaultValue>
        <Values>
          <Value>C:\Temp\Schemas\FiscalYearOverview.xml</Value>
        </Values>
      </DefaultValue>
      <Prompt>DataSource</Prompt>
      <Hidden>true</Hidden>
    </ReportParameter>
```

and DataSet like this:

```
<DataSet Name="TotalPortfolioValues">
      <Fields>
        <Field Name="Date">
          <DataField>Date</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.DateTime</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
            ...
      <Query>
        <DataSourceName>dsTotalGiro</DataSourceName>
        <CommandText>TotalPortfolioValues</CommandText>
        <QueryParameters>
          <QueryParameter Name="@DataSource">
            <Value>=Parameters!DataSource.Value</Value>
          </QueryParameter>
        </QueryParameters>
      </Query>
    </DataSet>
```

Create DataSet From BusinessObjectList and call ReportExecution using DataSet parameter:

https://github.com/aistrate/B4F/blob/f70276a5ac7d220b581d14e6d8e2f62d79083eea/TotalGiro/ApplicationLayer/Reports/ReportResultsAdapter.cs

```
    public static byte[] ViewPrintedReports(int managementCompanyId, int year, string reportLetterTypeName)
    {
        DataSet dsPrintedReports = GetPrintedReportsDataSet(managementCompanyId, year, reportLetterTypeName);

        ReportExecutionWrapper wrapper = new ReportExecutionWrapper();
        wrapper.SetReportName(getReportTemplateName(managementCompanyId, ReportReturnClass.ResultOfPrintedReport.ToString()));
        wrapper.AddParameters(new string[] { "SelectedReportYear" });

        return wrapper.GetReportContent(dsPrintedReports, new string[] { year.ToString() });
    }

    // Also used by DumpDataSets.aspx
    public static DataSet GetPrintedReportsDataSet(int managementCompanyId, int year, string reportLetterTypeName)
    {
        IDalSession session = NHSessionFactory.CreateSession();
        try
        {
            ReportLetterTypes reportLetterType = ReportLetterMapper.GetReportLetterType(reportLetterTypeName);

            DataSet dsPrintedReports = DataSetBuilder.CreateDataSetFromBusinessObjectList(
                        ReportMapper.GetReports(session, year, reportLetterType, managementCompanyId),
                        @"Key, Account.Key, ReportLetter.Key, ReportStatusId, ReportLetter.ReportLetterYear, ReportLetter.ReportLetterTypeId, 
                          ModelPortfolio.Key, ModelPortfolio.ModelName");

            return getPrintedReportsSummary(dsPrintedReports);
        }
        finally
        {
            session.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing. You're making it a lot more complicated than it actually is. Hopefully the following article can help you forward though: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms252109.aspx

Comment: @Oceans Wrapper class for ReportExecution:

https://github.com/aistrate/B4F/blob/f70276a5ac7d220b581d14e6d8e2f62d79083eea/TotalGiro/Reports/ReportExecutionWrapper.cs
GetReportContent method manage one DataSet. In RDL file Define ReportParameter "DataSource" (type String). Create DataSet From BusinessObjectList and call ReportExecution using DataSet parameter: **View Update Question**

Comment: RDL reports are used to display data from a database using datatables, so the objects you are trying to display on the report are represented by rows. So you're kind of limited to your datatable, you can create views and procedures to actually customize this however. If you wish to use an actual list of custom objects then I'm afraid you'll have to use RDLC. Which is basically the format used for programming.